# How to get the equation of an ellipse given the center, directrix and length of latus rectum?

Tags: elliptic-equations

Find the equation of the ellipse with centre $(5, -2)$, $x+3=0$ as the directrix, and length of the latus rectum equal to $6$.

Comment: I have forgotten what the latus rectum is and I would bet that most readers have never heard of it. What is it?

Comment: It is a chord of the ellipse passing through a focus and perpendicular to the major axis.